# How do I change the font of, and color the fill of the scatterplot?

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I would like to change the font and fill the background of the variables in my scatterplot. I've had no success.

```
crime <- read.csv('http://datasets.flowingdata.com/crimeRatesByState2005.csv',sep=",", header=TRUE)

crime2 <- crime[crime$state != "District of Columbia",]
crime2 <- crime2[crime2$state != "United States",]

windowsFonts(D=windowsFont("Georgia"))

pairs(crime2[,2:9]
      , panel=panel.smooth
      , col.smooth = "blue"
      , col="gray"
      , pch=16 #dot fill
      , labels=c("Murder","Forcible Rape","Robbery","Aggrevated \n Assault","Burglary","Larceny/Theft","Motor Vehicle \n Theft","Population")
      , font.labels=1 #normal
      , font.main=3 #italics
      , cex.labels=1.5 #size
      , las=1 #horizontal
      #, font.family="D"
      #, labels.family="D"
      #, cex.family="D"
      ) 
mtext("Rates per 100,000 population \n  \n ", side=3, adj=0, line=1.2, cex=1, font=3, family="D")
```

Comment: there is the `font` graphical parameter that allows you to do so. Check `?par`.

Comment: By "fill the background of the variables" what do you mean? Do you want to shade the background of the entire chart, shade the background of the data points (make them filled-in circles), or shade the background of the text labels, or something else?

Comment: in addition to `?par`, look at `?points`; some of the `pch` values accept a background fill color, others do not.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I did look up par and had no luck. To clarify, I want to change the font family to "Georgia" and set the background fill of the labels (ie Murder) to gray.

Comment: Rolled back to undo edits about point fill.

Comment: To change fonts, look at the `extrafont` package. To change the background shading of the labels on the diagonal of the pairs plot, you'll have to hack the function as it's hardcoded (see the `if (i == j)` parts of `pairs.default`).

Answer (score 0):

Try something to the effect of `plot(1:10, pch=21, col="black", bg="lightblue")`. You have to use a `pch` value that can have a background color (21 through 25, see `?points`), and you specify the outer color with `col` and the inner color with `bg` (see`?par` and/or `?points`).

As for the font, you might be referring to the `family` argument of `par()`. These can be graphical device specific (and different OS's use different default graphical devices; e.g., `par(family="Times")` gives Time New Roman on a Mac, but not PC), but some fonts like "serif", "sans", and "mono" work cross platform.